# How do I join on two non-unique columns in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to be able to join two models by a column which is not unique in either one.

```
class Ctystate(models.Model):
    ctystate_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    zip5 = models.IntegerField()
    [...]

class Addr2zip(models.Model):
    addr2zip_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ctystate = models.ForeignKey(Ctystate, db_column='zip5', to_field='zip5')
    zip5 = models.IntegerField()
    [...]
```

Using the ForeignKey field just results in a model validation error:

> Field 'zip5' under model 'Addr2zip' must have a unique=True constraint.

Is there any way I can join these two models using the 'zip5' field in both?  I do realize that this could result in duplicates in results but there are other protections against that that will be used in the filter.

I'd also prefer not to have an intermediate table.  If I have to, I can just write my own SQL but am trying to stick with the ORM as much as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: Why have `zip5` in both models? If there's realtion between them it's easy to get the `zip5` for every `Àddr2zip` object. Furthermore I do not think it makes sense to always define the primary keys manully if there's no need to. If the `zip5` would be unique in the `Ctystate` model you could also use it as a primary key, so the foreign key would automatically be represented by it!

Comment: zip5 comes that way in this dataset and this is what I am doing to relate the two for this purpose.  If altering the data structure is not an option, how would I go about doing this with a django model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single zip code in the US may contain >1 city. A city definitely can have > 1 zip code, so you need a ManyToMany relation there.

Further, a zip code can cross state line and there are cities that cross state lines (e.g. Kansas City), but formally each municipality belongs to only one state.

The data models will depend on how you want to interpret this.

Most likely you won't even need to run joins like that with reasonable models.

Something like this might work though of you want to keep your models without changes (you'll need to check the real table names):

```
addr_list = Ctystate.objects.extra(
    select = {
        'city_name': 'ctystate.name',
        'addr': 'addr2zip.address'
    },
    where = ['ctystate.zip5 = addr2zip.zip5'],
    tables = ['ctystate', 'addr2zip']#assuming that those are names in your table
)
```

Comment: I'm aware of these issues.  But this is for pre-existing datasets, and this is how I need to relate the two tables.

Comment: well, I guess I'd rather migrate data into new tables with South than write nasty queries. But it is possible to use extra() clauses to join that way if you have to. I'm afraid there is no way to avoid extra() call in this calse.

Comment: Know where I might get an example of .extra(tables=[])?  The docs don't give one(nor explain it very well). Of course those two simple words returns a million and one unrelated items on google as well.

Comment: you can also try printing the actual query `print addr_list.query` to see what it does in the sql

Comment: You need brackets around your where clause, but this appears to be what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to solve it like this:

```
class Ctystate(models.Model):
    ctystate_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    zip5 = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class Addr2zip(models.Model):
    addr2zip_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    ctystate = models.ForeignKey(Ctystate, db_column='zip5', to_field='zip5')
```

If you would do it like that, the `ForeignKey` `ctystate` will be represented by the value of `zip5` in a db column named `zip5`. If you want to use a foreign key realtion you must set the `to_field` to `unique=True` because otherwise it wouldn't be a 1:n (foreign key) relation anymore (every `Addr2zip` object could relate otherwise to more than one `Ctystate` object, which would be a m:n relation - if you need this you must solve it using a `ManyToManyField`!).

Comment: See the original post.  Using ForeignKey() in this way causes an error due to zip5 in ctystate not being unique.  ManyToMany will not work for what I want, either, considering I do not want to have an intermediate table.  Thanks anyway.